# Bash script to compare and generate csv datafile

Tags: bash, awk

I have two CSV files data1.csv and data2.csv the content is something like this (with headers) :

DATA1.csv

```
Client Name;strnu;addr;fav
MAD01;HDGF;11;V PO
CVOJF01;HHD-;635;V T
LINKO10;DH--JDH;98;V ZZ
```

DATA2.csv

```
USER;BINin;TYPE
XXMAD01XXXHDGFXX;11;N
KJDGD;635;M
CVOJF01XXHHD;635;N
```

Issues :

- The value of the 1st and 2nd column of DATA1.csv exist randomly in the first column of DATA2.csv.
  For example `MAD01;HDGF` exist in the first column of DATA2 `***MAD01***HDGF**` (`*` can be alphanum and/or symbols charachter) and `MAD01;HDGF` might not be in the same order in the column `USER` of DATA2.
- The value of strnum in DATA1 is equal to the value of the column BINin in DATA2
- The column fav DATA1 is the same as TYPE in DATA2 because `V T = M` and `V PO = N` (some other valuses may exist but we won't need them for example line 3 of DATA1 it should be ignored)

N.B: some data may exist in a file but not the other.

my bash script needs to generate a new CSV file that should contain:

- The column `USER` from DATA2
- `Client Name` and `strnu` from DATA1
- `BINin` from DATA2 only if it's equal to the corespondent line and value of `strnu` DATA1
- `TYPE` using `M` `N` Format and making sure to respect the condition that `V T = M` and `V PO = N`

The first thing i tried was usuing grep to search for lines that exist in both files

```
#!/bin/sh

DATA1="${1}"
DATA2="${2}"

for i in $(cat $DATA1 | awk -F";" '{print $1".*"$2}' | sed 1d) ; do
   grep "$i" $DATA2
done
```

Result :

```
$ ./script.sh DATA1.csv DATA2.csv
MAD01;HDGF;11;V PO
XXMAD01XXXHDGFXX;11;N
CVOJF01;HHD-;635;V T
LINKO10;DH--JDH;98;V PO
```

Using grep and awk i could find lines that are present in DATA1 and DATA2 files but it doesn't work for all the lines and i guess it's because of the `-` and other special characters present in column 2 of DATA1 but they can be ignored.

I don't know how i can generate a new csv that would mix the lines present in both files but the expected generated CSV should look like this

```
USER;Client Name;strnu;BINin;TYPE
XXMAD01XXXHDGFXX;MAD01;HDGF;11;N
CVOJF01XXHHD;CVOJF01;HHD-;635;M
```

Comment: what are we supposed to do with hyphens from the 1st file - `HHD-` and `DH--JDH` - ignore them? treat them as wildcards? something else? are there any other 'special' characters (other than hyphens) that need special processing?

Comment: what's the expected result if the 1st file has `V T` but the 2nd file has `X` or `JTE` or another-other-value-except-M

Comment: when matching values from the 1st file (client name, strnu(m)) do they have to appear in the same order in the 2nd file, eg, if 1st file is `ABC;DEF` will this match `DEF_ABC` in the 2nd file?

Comment: @markp-fuso - for the hyphens they can be ignored - if the first file has V T the second will always have M same vor `V PO` the second file contains either M or N Value but the first file can have values other than V T or V PO and they can be ignored too like the 3th line of DATA1 - no they don't necessarily apear in the same order but ABC;DEF will always match one uniq ligne in the second file either **DEF****ABC** or *ABC***DEF** the *s might be alphanum or symbol with different length

Comment: What I understand you're saying is that it does not matter that there is a relationship between "fav" and "TYPE" -- validating that is not a requirement. Essentially, all that can be removed from your question since it's just causing confusion. Right?

Comment: when you say we can `ignore` the `fav` value from `DATA1.csv` are you saying we don't need to test/compare the value of the `fav` column? or are you saying we should ignore the entire line (from `DATA1.csv`) if `fav` is not one of `V T` or `V PO`?

Comment: @glennjackman there is a relation between "fav" and "TYPE". if "fav"="v T" then "TYPE"=M and  if "fav"="V PO" then "TYPE"=N and other lines where "fav" have values that are not "V T" or "V PO" can be totally ignored

Comment: in the last line of the expected output why does the line end with `635;M` instead of the `635;N` from `DATA2.csv` (ie, `N` vs `M`)? is that a typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done in a single awk program. This is `join.awk`

```
BEGIN {
    FS = OFS = ";"
    print "USER", "Client Name", "strnu", "BINin", "TYPE"
}

FNR == 1 {next}

NR == FNR {
    strnu[$1] = $2
    next
}

{
    for (client in strnu) {
        strnu_pattern = strnu[client]
        gsub(/-/, "", strnu_pattern)

        if ($1 ~ client && $1 ~ strnu_pattern) {
            print $1, client, strnu[client], $2, $3
            break
        }
    }
}
```

and then

```bash
awk -f join.awk DATA1.csv DATA2.csv
```

outputs

```
USER;Client Name;strnu;BINin;TYPE
XXMAD01XXXHDGFXX;MAD01;HDGF;11;N
CVOJF01XXHHD;CVOJF01;HHD-;635;N
```

Comment: A lot shorter than my answer +1; I would check `$1 ~ client ".*" strnu[client]` for avoiding possible overlaps

Comment: ... Done. Thanks for the sharp eyes. It would be a touch shorted with gawk's gensub.

Comment: @Fravadona, we'd need `$1 ~ client ".*" strnu[client] || $1 ~ strnu[client] ".*" client`

Answer (score 2):

Assumptions/understandings:

- ignore lines from `DATA1.csv` where the `fav` field is not one of `V T` or `V PO`
- when matching fields we need to ignore the any hyphens from the `DATA1.csv` fields
- when matching fields the strings from `DATA1.csv` can show up in either order in `DATA2.csv`
- last line of the expected output show end with `635,N`

One `awk idea:

```
awk '
BEGIN   { FS=OFS=";"
          print "USER","Client Name","strnu","BINin","TYPE"   # print new header
        }
FNR==1  { next }                                              # skip input headers
FNR==NR { if ($4 == "V PO" || $4 == "V T") {                  # only process if fav is one of "V PO" or "V T"
             cnames[FNR]=$1                                   # save client name
             strnus[FNR]=$2                                   # save strnu
          }
          next
        }
        { for (i in cnames) {                                 # loop through array indices
              cname=cnames[i]                                 # make copy of client name ...
              strnu=strnus[i]                                 # and strnu so that we can ...
              gsub(/-/,"",cname)                              # strip hypens from both ...
              gsub(/-/,"",strnu)                              # in order to perform the comparisons ...
              if (index($1,cname) && index($1,strnu)) {       # if cname and strnu both exist in $1 then index()>=1 in both cases so ...
                 print $1,cnames[i],strnus[i],$2,$3           # print to stdout
                 next                                         # we found a match so break from loop and go to next line of input
              }
          }
        }
' DATA1.csv DATA2.csv
```

This generates:

```
USER;Client Name;strnu;BINin;TYPE
XXMAD01XXXHDGFXX;MAD01;HDGF;11;N
CVOJF01XXHHD;CVOJF01;HHD-;635;N
```